# How to make time change on ToolTip as event is dragged or Resized?

Tags: fullcalendar, tooltip

When displayEventTime: true the times show on the events and when the events are dragged or resized the time accurately change in real time on the event. What do I need to add to my code to have the Tooltip popup change the time accurately in realtime as well? Variables line1 and line2 is the start and end time. CodePen link provided below, Thank you

```
  var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
    title: line1 + " " + line2,
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'hover',
    container: 'body'
  });
  
  // events can have multiple parts, so make an array for each event and add all it's tooltips
  var tooltips = info.event.extendedProps['tooltips'] || [];
  tooltips.push(tooltip);      
  info.event.setExtendedProp('tooltips', tooltips);
  
},
eventWillUnmount: function(info) {
  for (var tooltip of info.event.extendedProps['tooltips']) {
    tooltip.dispose();
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/asilver666666/pen/ExgPZaV